# Linq ForEach in string interpolation

Tags: c#, linq

In order to make my code superclear, I'm trying to do something like that:

```
var result = $@"...
<div class='modal-body'>
    {content}
</div>
{(haveButtons ? "" : "<div class='modal-footer'>")}
{modalButtons.ForEach(m => "INSERT SOME HTML")}
{(haveButtons ? "" : "</div>")}
..."
```

But, of course, that doesn't compile because in the lambda I need to put some code and not just a magic return. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to do and what the problem is when you do so. Personally I wouldn't want to start adding a lot of code in interpolated strings though. Additionally, `ForEach` doesn't return a value - so how do you expect to use it in an interpolated string?

Comment: Frankly, this is all but *superclear*. Depending on which framework you're in you probably should use partial views or bindings.

Comment: This looks like a double inner-platform concept, you're manually constructing HTML with strings, with code inside those strings again. I urge you to find a better way to structure this code.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I will try to move to a partial view, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{string.Join("", modalButtons.Select(m => "INSERT SOME HTML"))}
```